# How to run Spec Test Cases dynamically as per user decision in excel sheet by using flag "YES" in protractor

Tags: gulp, protractor

Is their is any way to run spec test in protractor dynamically as per user decision in excel sheet by using flag "YES".If the flag is "YES" then that test should start run.
if it is not possible, then any alternative for that either through gulp task or by some other method??

Comment: Could you provide more details about the motivation behind this kind of a requirement? Why does it have to be an excel sheet?

Comment: In case of TestNg, we can include/exclude the test-method during suite creation as per the  value of "YES" or "NO" in Excel sheet in front of the method name  .So, tester can just change the method to be include for execution by doing flag value to be "YES", he/she don't need to modify the code. Same i want to do in the case of protractor